# xtype instead of alias in class definition

Tags: extjs, extjs4, xtype

Is there any difference between the two following class definition methods?

```
Ext.define("Test", {
  extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
  xtype: "test"
});

Ext.define("Test", {
  extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
  alias: "widget.test"
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is said that the alias is faster, but I don't think you will notice. I use alias when defining classes and xtype when creating objects, just a personal convention, so I don't get confused.

Answer (score 16):

As Eddy already stated, there is no difference in the result in case of a `xtype`.

**But the alias property can more then a xtype...**

The main difference is that `alias` can be used to define all sort of aliases (widgets, plugins, features, layouts, etc.) while `xtype` already is a specific shorthand for a alias type, a `widget`. So if you use `xtype` you can only define widgets, nothing else. In addition the `alias` property makes the code a bit more readable and should therefore be the first choice when writing class definitions.

Here are the common aliases of versions 4.2.3

- association
- axis
- data
- direct
- editing
- feature
- formaction
- idgen
- layout
- plugin
- proxy
- reader
- selection
- series
- state
- store
- widget
- writer